# Assure that the data is loaded in a view without an individual request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty sure there must be an elegant solution for that pattern in angular, I just can't see it.

## The problem:

- All data is loaded once in a bulk on the start of the application.
- The user requests a certain view (like `/#/users/13`) by entering a URL
- Problem: the data hasn't loaded yet

### The server

My backend server returns **all** available data from all its tables at once (it isn't much) as JSON

```
{users: [...], groups: [...], stuff: [...], ...}
```

### The service

I wrapped that in an angular service with an `update()` Method, that will, on success, put the elements of the response in `$rootScope`, because that's what the whole application is working on:

```
.success(function (data) {
    $rootScope.users = data.users;
    $rootScope.groups = data.groups;
    ...
}
```

The update method is called in the mainController once the app starts.

### The controller/view

When I create a view for a certain user, like `/users/:id`, everything works fine navigating inside the application. So far, so good.

When I start the application with a deep link to a view like `#/users/13`, the data has not been loaded yet, so the controller can not link the data as usual, resulting in an error:

```
$scope.user = $scope.users[$routeParams.id];
```

## Ideas

All ideas I had to solve this are problematic one way or another.

- Reacting on the non-defined `$scope.users` in the controller would avoid the error, but how would I reload the view once the data is there?
- Setting up a `resolve` section for the route with a dependency on a promise of that service result would reload *every* time the route is used, even if the data is already loaded (data should be loaded only on the start of the app)
- Setting up a service for each of the data parts and using a promise on each result would fetch the data many times from the server
- Setting an explicit flag for 'data is loaded' and changing things based on it's state seems completely wrong to me
- Working with promises gives me some headaches generally, as there is only one big bulk of fetched data, but we want to refer the single elements of it

So I'm afraid I'm just missing the "Angular way" for that kind of setup (probably just beeing blind).

Comment: *When I start the application with a deep link* --- how is angular loaded then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data that should always be loaded you can load it in your apps "app.run". This is always done before anything else. It won't save you from having to wait from http-requests since it is still async, but you can use it to make sure that the data is always loaded from the server (and only once, since app.run is only run once). Once you get the data you can store it in a service or in the rootScope so that controllers and others can use it.

That takes care of making sure the call to load the data is always run and that is only ever run once. The second part would be waiting for the data, for that I would still use a resolve.

1. Check the service or rootScope to see if the data already exists.
2. If if it did, then great.
3. If not, use watch to wait for it.
4. When the promise is resolved, show the view.

By storing the data in a service I mean using something like this:

```
app.factory('DataObject', [function(){
  return {};
}]);
```

Services are singletons so anything using this object will share the same data. So the resolve can depend on it and use it to check if the data exists. You could also use the rootScope for the same thing, but using a service saves you from littering in the rootScope. rootScope is easier to watch through.

---

Edit: If you wanted to go the way of checking in your controller if the data is ready yet then you want [$scope.$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) to trigger things once the data loads in.

Comment: That brings me much closer to what I need, but still has the issue of triggering an additional request of the data when the view is requested while they actually load.

Comment: I'll add a new comment about that.

Comment: Btw, is this data that should always be loaded, or should it only load on certain routes?

Comment: Updated the answer. In essence, use app.run to make the call for the data and then use resolve to wait until it is done. Where I work we use this to load a users data on login, to make sure we always have it available.